# Selenium using 2Captcha to solve Geetest Verification

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

I am using Selenium to doing browser automation.
However, recently they update Geetest verification.
I am register 2Captcha service, but when I gather the gt, challenge, api-server from rendered code.
It's not working for using 2Captcha solving service due to the gt, challenge, api-server these 3 variable are not same as when click submit form to do Geetest verification. I have tried several way as followed:

1. Using mob proxy to catch response of geetest site 3 value. => But cannot integrate my own proxy.
2. Tring to use PIL to calulate the gap of slide pictures => very slow and sometime internet speed effect successful rate.
3. Try to use requests to replace Selenium => I am no expert on this always got block and error when connect to target site.
4. Chrome web log to analyze to find out responsed 3 value =>I keep reading but most article is not work in current version of Python.

Any one can help or hint how to do with Python Selenium to use 2Captcha to solve Geetest?
My targety site is : http://app.stormgain.com, I want to do is auto login.